# how can i add all product and update a data in another table

Tags: php, sql, stock, inventory

i have 2 tables tb1=storage and tb2=daily_quota iwant to add all product with the same name in tb2 and update the finished_product in table1

example table
table1=storage

| product_name | finished_product |
| --- | --- |
| Ascorbic Kids | 30 |
| Ascorbic Adults | 20 |

table2=daily_quota

| product_name | finished_product |
| --- | --- |
| Ascorbic Kids | 30 |
| Ascorbic Adults | 30 |
| Ascorbic Kids | 30 |
| Ascorbic Adults | 30 |
| Ascorbic Kids | 30 |
| Ascorbic Adults | 30 |

how can i sum all product_name = Ascorbic Kids.finished_product in table2=daily_quota
and update the table1 =storage product_name = Ascorbic Kids finished_product = value of the sum in table2=daily_quota

expected result

table1=storage

| product_name | finished_product |
| --- | --- |
| Ascorbic Kids | 90 |
| Ascorbic Adults | 90 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: thank you for your response. I input now what i expect result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose to make table1 a view, that you can use as needed.

The view would look like that:

```
CREATE VIEW storage AS
SELECT product_name, SUM(finished_product) as quantity
FROM table2
GROUP BY product_name
```

Comment: its working now i can see the sum of my product but if iwant to update the value of my table1=storage finished_product = quantity what would i need to do?

Comment: You do not need to update the value of your table1. In practice, the view storage is the table1. Views can be used in queries as tables and even be materialized if you need that. If you have other properties in table1 that you have not included in the question, you might need to do a join between the view and the table.